# Azure Machine Learning REST Endpoint - Failed to Fetch

Tags: azure, rest, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-static-web-app

I created an Azure Machine Learning model with a REST Endpoint as a way to consume it. When I run the service using Postman everything seems to work fine.

However, when I try to create an HTML website (Codepen) with a javascript to call the REST Endpoint I only get an Error: Failed to Fetch message.

I also tried with Azure Static Web Apps and I am unsuccessful as well.

I was however able to verify (in the Console) that my input to the Rest Endpoint via Codepen is the same as Postman.

Is there anything I am missing out here?

Here is a sample of my javascript:

```
<script>
const form = document.querySelector('#agriculture-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const areaHarvest = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#area-harvest').value);
    const farmGatePrice = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#farm-gate-price').value);
    const volumeOfImport = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#volume-of-import').value);
    const lowTemp = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#low-temp').value);
    const averageTemp = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#average-temp').value);
    const highTemp = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#high-temp').value);
    const precipitationMm = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#precipitation-mm').value);
    const precipitationDays = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#precipitation-days').value);
    const tropicalCyclones = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#tropical-cyclones').value);
    const volumeProductionGuess = 0;

    const data = {
        "Area_Harvested": areaHarvest,
        "FarmGatePricePHPPSA": farmGatePrice,
        "Volume_of_Import": volumeOfImport,
        "temp_low": lowTemp,
        "temp_ave": averageTemp,
        "temp_high": highTemp,
        "precipitation_mm": precipitationMm,
        "precipitation_days": precipitationDays,
        "tropical_cyclone": tropicalCyclones,
        "Volume_of_Production": volumeProductionGuess
    };

    const formattedData = [data];
    console.log('formatted data:', formattedData);
    const testData = JSON.stringify(formattedData);
    console.log('test data:', testData);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testData;

    fetch('http://ziggyapimanagementservice.azure-api.net/score', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'cd529cc993494fdfb1530eaf04ae63dc'
        },
        body: testData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            const result = data.result[0]; // Get the result array from the response
            const volumeForecastElement = document.querySelector('#volume-forecast');
            volumeForecastElement.textContent = result.join(', '); // Update the text content of the <b> element with the result array joined by commas
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {

            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error.message;
            console.error(error.message)
        });
});
```

And here is what I get in Postman:
[image]

update:
I added the CORS setting in the Azure API Management and still has the issue:
[image]

3-10-2023 update: I added the Accept Header in the Javascript and removed the access key for the moment. Also changed the API to HTTPS just to see if things change.Also changed the CORS value in the API
[image]

[image]

It works with Postman though but not with the Javascript:
[image]

Last Update: Changed CORS again and it now works!
[image]

Comment: Can you shows Postmana's succussed screens with required information (endpoint, modelUri and other)?

Comment: @BenchVue i added my JS and the Postman sample

Comment: I can get the result by Postman but I try to call by script, can't get the result. Fetch did not POST call.

Comment: @BenchVue same here so i dont know why

Comment: I don't know either, let's wait someone help your problem

Comment: What error did you get @Ziggy? Please, be sure that your REST endpoint is sending the `allow-*` CORS related headers appropriate for your javascript application, it could be very likely related to your problem.

Comment: @jccampanero it is related to that but the endpoint has no way im told to allow CORS

Comment: @jccampanero I was on vacation but couldnt reply back.. anyways, I added the CORS setting as per your suggestion and I still get the issue

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @Ziggy. I even removed the answer... Please, can you review it? I included further alternatives. Please, could you try?

Comment: @jccampanero added your answers as seen in the update above.. still nothing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, the error could be very likely related to a CORS problem.

Please, consider configuring your REST endpoint for sending the CORS headers appropriate for your Javascript application.

You seem to be using API Management for exposing the REST endpoint: if that is correct, you can configure CORS by defining the appropriate [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies).

This page provides the necessary information about [how to set or edit API Management policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies?tabs=form).

The CORS policy is documented in [this other page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/cors-policy). The documentation provides [a sample configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/cors-policy#example), adapted for your use case:

```xml
<cors allow-credentials="true">
    <allowed-origins>
        <!-- Localhost useful for development -->
        <origin>http://localhost:8080/</origin>
        <origin>http://your-javascript-app-domain.com/</origin>
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
        <method>POST</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>content-type</header>
        <header>accept</header>
    </allowed-headers>
</cors>
```

[This related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244072/how-configure-azure-api-management-for-cors) could be of help as well.

Additionally, please, consider including an [`Accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) when posting your information, we have experienced problems when this header is not present when invoking an API exposed by the API Management service, I am not absolutely sure, but I think it is not included by default by `fetch` (in contrast to Postman):

```js
fetch('http://ziggyapimanagementservice.azure-api.net/score', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'cd529cc993494fdfb1530eaf04ae63dc'
        },
        body: testData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            const result = data.result[0]; // Get the result array from the response
            const volumeForecastElement = document.querySelector('#volume-forecast');
            volumeForecastElement.textContent = result.join(', '); // Update the text content of the <b> element with the result array joined by commas
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {

            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error.message;
            console.error(error.message)
        });
```

Comment: @Ziggy Were you able to test the proposed solution?

Comment: @Ziggy I included an alternative solution in the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I did what you mentioned..added Accept Header and Added the CORS setting. still nothing :(

Comment: @Thank you very much for the feedback @Ziggy. Please, could you try two more things? First, could you include `https://cdpn.io` in your CORS configuration? That is actually the domain from which Codepen sends the requests to the application. If that doesn't work, please, could you remove `<base/>` from your `<inbound>` definition in API Management? I still think that the error is motivated by CORS.

Comment: wow yes it does indeed work. Thank you so much!! You have helped me tons! Now If I would create a static Web app and Azure for this, what should i put in the domain?

Comment: That is nice @Ziggy, I am happy to hear that it is working fine now. Regarding your question, when you create the Static Wep App, Azure auto-generates a domain name for your website, something like `https://<random words>/azurestaticapps.net/`. That is the domain you need to include in your CORS configuration.  If you prefer to, you could define a [custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain) for the website as well: in that case, it should be the one you need to provide in your CORS configuration.

Comment: oh thanks let me try this. for codepen how did you know it was https://cdpn.io. Where did it say btw?

Comment: Of course, I hope it helps. Regarding codepen, please, see the errors provided in the browser development console, in case of CORS related problems it will indicate the host from which the requests are being sent, in this case, cpdn.io.

Comment: @Ziggy Please, forgive me to point it out but, if you want to award the bounty, you must do it explicitly because the answer was posted before you started it. Again, sorry,  but it is always very frustrating for both the OP and the person who provides the answer to realize that the bounty is lost for that reason.

Comment: oh sorry! I thought accepting the answer was awarding it!!!!

Comment: Please, there is no need to say sorry @Ziggy. In the end the only important thing is that you were able to solve the problem.